# Big-O for $\Sigma_{i = 1}^{N} i \times \binom{N}{i}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, np-complete

How to solve Big-O for $\Sigma_{i = 1}^{N} i \times \binom{N}{i}$? Can I simply say it is in $O(N!)$?

Comment: It is true. If it is a satisfactory answer in your context is impossible to know without knowing that context. Please include some context via an [edit]

Comment: There is a simple closed-form expression for your sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is true, but we can get a better upper bound by observing that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\binom{N}{i}\binom{i}{1}=\sum_{i=1}^N N\binom{N-1}{i-1}=N\sum_{u=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{u}=N2^{N-1}
$$
where we have used the identity
$$
\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{k-r}\quad (n\ge k\geq r\geq 0)
$$
as well as the fact that
$$
2^n=(1+1)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}
$$
by the binomial theorem.